# Spawn enemies does not work good in spritekit / swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2, sprite

I want to sequentially spawn enemies. So wrote a code for that, but can't understand why just two of first enemies appears on right position, and the rest of them spawn on wrong positions. Here is the code:

```
func addDoor() {
    for i in 0...1 {
        let doorSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Door")
        doorSprite.name = "door\(i)"
        if i == 0 {
            doorSprite.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2.0 - 40.0 - doorSprite.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height - doorSprite.frame.size.height / 2.0)
        } else {
            doorSprite.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2.0 + 40.0 + doorSprite.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height - doorSprite.frame.size.height / 2.0)
        }
        gameLayer.addChild(doorSprite)
    }
}

func enemySpawn() {
    for i in 0..<15 {
        let sprite = Enemy(imageNamed: "Enemy")
        sprite.name = "enemy\(i)"

        let randDoor = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))

            if randDoor == 0 {
                if let door = gameLayer.childNodeWithName("door\(randDoor)") {
                    sprite.position = CGPointMake((door.position.x - door.frame.size.width / 2.0) + spawnPoint(UInt32(door.frame.size.width - sprite.frame.size.width)) + sprite.frame.size.width / 2.0, door.position.y)
                }
            } else {
                if let door = homeLayer.childNodeWithName("door\(randDoor)") {
                    sprite.position = CGPointMake((door.position.x - door.frame.size.width / 2.0) + spawnPoint(UInt32(door.frame.size.width - sprite.frame.size.width)) + sprite.frame.size.width / 2.0, door.position.y)
                }
            }
        }

        enemiesLayer.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(i)), completion: {
            self.enemiesLayer.addChild(sprite)
        })

    }
}

func spawnPoint(num: UInt32) -> CGFloat {
    let randomSpawn: CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(num))
    return randomSpawn
}
```

Comment: It isn't possible to tell from your code what the 'right' or 'wrong' positions would be.

Comment: First method adds two doors in the scene. Then i want to spawn sequentially enemies on one of these doors. So in the second function only adds two enemies to the doors, and the rest of them appears in CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0),  it should appears where doors stay, though.

Comment: Something wrong, where optional binding in 'if let door = gameLayer.childNodeWithName("door\(randDoor)")'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, the logic in both the `if` and `else` blocks is exactly the same.

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here or how the `randDoor` variable is supposed to be used, but the whole `if - else` block isn't doing anything.

Comment: There are two doors which are used to be spawn point. Both of them stays at different positions. So each of enemy have to be spawn randomly.

Comment: And the if - else statements for calculating different spawn points on each enemy!

Comment: OK - But `randDoor` will only ever be `0` or `1`. Whether it is `0` or `1`, exactly the same code executes.

Comment: I'm just updated the code above. Yes, because there two door, each of them has different positions in the layer. When i spawn one enemy, its calculates one of these doors and adds enemy to them, and next enemy appears in another door or maybe in the same door, its randomly, and so on. So if-else statements needs to calculate which door can spawn the enemy.

Comment: Thanks i found the mistake! tebs1200 like!